# What does it mean for a function of $n$ variables to be of class $\mathsf{C^2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I have a rather trivial question.

The book states: "Assume that the function of $n$ variables $f$ is of class $\mathsf{C^2}$."

I know that $\mathsf{C}$ is the complex set, but how about squared? What can I conclude from that.

Sorry for my silly question.

Comment: $C$ here has nothing to do with the complex numbers; it stands for (as far as I know) "continuous(ly differentiable)." Class $C^2$ means the second derivatives exist and are continuous.

Comment: Just a comment on notation. Usually blackboard font is used to denote complex numbers: $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

A function of one variable is said to be of class $\mathcal{C}^k$ if it is $k$-times continuously differentiable.

In the case of functions of more than one variable, we say a function is of class $\mathcal{C}^k$ if all partial derivatives of order $k$ exist and are continuous.

Comment: This is correct. Although if it is not clear from context, it would be better to write e.g. $\mathcal C^k(\mathbb R^n)$, which I'm supposing is what the author intended.